# Assigning and adding

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

How would I write the code to create a script called "add" in which there are three variables and assign these variables the values – 10, 12, 15. The script then needs to add these variables together and print the answer.

Comment: We're not really a script-writing service, but if you have a go and get stuck I'm sure someone here will help. You can check your code syntax at https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: Here's a nice reference on the subject I ran across about a year ago... [Math Arithmetic: How To Do Calculation in Bash?](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/math-arithmetic-calculation/)

Answer (score 0):

Google is your best friend

```
a=10
b=12
c=15

echo $(( a + b + c ))
```